# Deleting rules from Stack Exchange filters

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, tag-filters

Is it possible to delete or change rules from Stack Exchange filters, or do you need to make a completely new filter? If not I would like to request such a feature since filter lists could grow pretty big depending on ones interest.

Comment: There's a word named "edit" just above the list. Click it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 yeah but there is no way to remove a single tag when editing filters or is there? I would expect it to be there but i searched myself blind. It seems you can turn questions on and off though.